Calculus differential rates problem, Calculus for the practical man chapter IV problem 14
This is a problem from Calculus for the Practical Man by J.E. Thompson which regards a 50 ft rope bypassing a pulley 25 ft high, pulled by a man moving at a rate of 10 ft per second 5 ft off level ground. I'm studying calculus in advance because it is an interesting topic and I know it'll be difficult later on. My working out is incorrect according to the book with an answer of 6 ft per second, I'd like to review my logical errors in the working out and would appreciate a worked solution with the correct answer.


Please don't use pictures.

Don't use pictures. Let $L(t)$ be the length between the man and the pulley. Then $L(t)^2 = x^2+20^2$ and you want ${d L(t) \over d t}$ at $x=15$. Note that $L(0) = 25$. Now differentiate the equation.

The answer is indeed obtained by differentiating a function dependent on time, representative of the distance from the pulley to the man. The function is:
$$
L(t) = \sqrt{x^2 + 20^2}
$$
The derivative of $L(t)$ with respect to time is:
$$
\frac{dL(t)}{dt} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 400}} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}
$$
Since $ \frac{dx}{dt} = 10 $, we get:
$$
\frac{dL(t)}{dt} = \frac{10x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 400}}
$$
This gives a speed of 6 feet per second when $x = 15$.
Full credit to copper.hat, thanks very much.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Thank you for the references to formatting that helps a lot
